# python3.7 install on mac not recognized in terminal

Tags: python

I installed python3.7 using:

```
brew install python@3.7
```

Then I did:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/sony/.bash_profile
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/lib"
```

When I do:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
```

I get:

```
Python 3.7.10 (default, Apr 27 2021, 08:48:55)
```

Which means it works
but when I do:

```
python3.7
```

I get:

```
-bash: python3.7: command not found
```

Not sure what I missed here?

Comment: pls, try python or python3.

Comment: which shell are you using? the default now is zsh which uses .zprofile instead of .bash_profile

Comment: @simpleApp python gives me 2.7 and python3 gives me 3.6 which both were installed before i tried to install 3.7 that is fine. I want them to stay and have 3.7 configured to python3.7

Comment: along with .zsh shell changes. an alternative way would be to manage your dependencies through a virtual environment. something to refer [virtual env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that you could try:

- Make sure your path is correct and properly connected
- Go to `users>your_user` then click on `Cmd+shift+.` this way you will be able to access the hidden files, then proceed to open the `.bash_profile` and make sure the export path is properly entered/or enter it and save. (remember to refresh the terminal before running the python command)
- Try typing just python3 in the terminal, the terminal should automatically recognize which version of python you are working on.
- You could add your export path to `.zshrc` file and shift to the zsh terminal by entering `chsh -s /bin/zsh`

Comment: Thanks! Look like all I needed was to refresh the terminal!

Answer (score 0):

So by default, you can run python3 command but not run python command until you set the PATH and env vars in Mac.

Check if python is installed: ***which python3***

If yes, then you need to check the info with this command

```
 brew info python
```

In the output you will find the path where python is installed, something like this:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/libexec/bin
```

So you need to run this commands by providing the above path:

```
echo 'export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/libexec/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zprofile
```

After that in the new terminal, or if you want to use the same terminal run this command

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

Now you can see the path with this command:

```
echo $PATH;
```

After that, you can run the ***python*** command.